# What's the difference of CreateNeg of `IRBuilderBase` and `BinaryOperator` in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to implement not operator in my toy programming language, I found two documents about `CreateNeg` API:

1. IRBuilderBase:
   https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilderBase.html#ab28ac8603fca1b03dbd98c4d48170aef
2. BinaryOperator:
   https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#a19cdbeffd437228c47a4410a4ed34aca

What's the difference between these 2 APIs ? Why `IRBuilderBase` has `CreateFNeg` API while `BinaryOperator` doesn't have it ?